# having a problem when converting firebase timestamp in standard format

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am getting the following error:

> object are not valid as a react child (found thu may 09 2019 17:25:13
>   GMT + 0500(PKT)).If tou meant to render a collection of children,use
>   an array instead

My Code:

```
<Body>
 <Text style={{ fontSize: 18 }}>
 {this.item.timestamp.toDate()}
 </Text>
</Body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error

> object are not valid as a react child

states that you are passing an object to the `<Text/>` Component, but only string literals are allowed.

You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to format/convert your timestamps.

You can install it with: `npm install moment`

If your timestamp is in **unix miliseconds** you can use:

```
import Moment from 'moment'; 
...
<Text> {Moment(this.item.timestamp).format("MM/DD/YYYY")} </Text>
```

If your timestamp is in **unix seconds** you can use:

```
import Moment from 'moment'; 
...
<Text> {Moment.unix(this.item.timestamp).format("MM/DD/YYYY")} </Text>
```

Working example:

https://snack.expo.io/HkTGLnfn4

Comment: my timestamp is like timestamp(second=1557404713,nanoseconds=532000000)

Comment: @ImranAli If my answer helped you, please upvote and mark my answer as accepted (to do this, click the check icon beside my answer).  Thank you